# Write to webpage letter by letter

Tags: hyperlink, autoit

So i'm busy with AutoIt, i am now using this code

```
 _IEPropertySet($passwordnew, "innertext", "12345678910")
```

This will paste the text "12345678910" into the Textbox of the webpage, is it possible to let it type it letter for letter? Not that it paste the whole concept. I already tried several stuff but it resulted in many errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why? You can try something like this:

```
Global $passwordnew = StringSplit(12345678910, '', 2)
Global $valueOfPasswortField = ''

For $i = 0 To UBound($passwordnew) - 1
;~  $valueOfPasswortField &= $passwordnew[$i]
;~  ConsoleWrite($valueOfPasswortField & @CRLF)
    _IEPropertySet($passwordnew, "innertext", _IEPropertyGet($passwordnew, "innertext") & $passwordnew[$i])
Sleep(400)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need a OnKeyUp event fired

```
$password = "1234567890"
_IEPropertySet($passwordnew, "innertext", "12345678910")
BlockInput(1)
_IEAction($passwordnew, "focus")
Send($password, 1)
BlockInput(0)
```

or

```
_IEPropertySet($passwordnew, "innertext", "12345678910")
$passwordnew.fireEvent("onkeyup")
```